# Não deixar o scroll ficar a 'meio', ficar num elemento ou noutro

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento

Antes demais queria pedir desculpa pelo titulo da pergunta, não encontrei maneira melhor de explicar.
O que eu quero é uma página 'normal', que tem por ex: 5 secções, queria que no scroll nós não vissemos metade de um uma e metade de outra, ou seja no final do evento mousewhell ou scroll 'manual', a página fosse emediatamente para o elemento seguinte ou anterior (dependendo da direção, cima ou baixo) mas nunca entre os dois. o meu caso no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b31vmpar/2/) até agora.

HTML:

```
<div id="acti1" class="acti" data-scrollTo="1"></div>
<div id="acti2" class="acti" data-scrollTo="2"></div>
<div id="acti3" class="acti" data-scrollTo="3"></div>
<div id="acti4" class="acti" data-scrollTo="4"></div>
<div id="acti5" class="acti" data-scrollTo="5"></div>
```

JS:

```
var navHeight = $('nav').height();
$('.acti').height($(window).height() - navHeight);

var rmLast = parseInt($('.acti').last().attr("data-scrollTo")) - 1;
$('.acti').slice(0, rmLast).click(function(){
    var scrollTo = parseInt($(this).attr("data-scrollTo"));
    $('body, html').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('.acti').eq(scrollTo).offset().top - navHeight
        });
    });

$(window).scroll(function(){
    ....
});
```

Comment: Miguel, se o scroll volta para trás por exemplo para nõ deixar mostrar só metade como queres que seja possivel passar para a proxima div? Queres um efeito tipo elástico que "parte" para a proxima se o scroll for "forte" sufeciente?

Comment: Bom dia @sergio, é dependo da direcção do scroll, se fizer para baixo vai para a secção de baixo para cima vai para a secção de cima, para além disso gostava também de põr links noutras páginas que indicassem para que secção gostaríamos que fosse ex: index.php#secção2 mas que não ficasse por baixo da barra de nav, ou seja, tinha de ser index.php#secção2 + altura da barra de nav (px)

Comment: Basicamente eu queria que em nenhuma circunstancia, nós vissemos duas secções, ou viamos a de cima ou a de baixo consoante o scroll

Comment: Mas queres algum scroll ou nenhum scroll? Se não queres scroll podias ter uma página do tamanho do ecrã com as divs com position fixed, top -1000px e depois fazeres css transitions do top para `0` da div que queres ver. Isso com direção do scroll?

Comment: Olha sim isso pararece ser mesmo a solução, mas atenção porque vai haver a barra de navegação fixed top também, tal e qual o jsfiddle que linkei, mas caso scroll para cima aperece a secção de cima e vice-versa, também terá dois botões para ir para as secções cima/baixo. Tem alguma solução simples para isso? Obragdo